# Adjective clause

Tags: questions

I want to make my sentence fluent so is the following sentence is correct?   If not then how should I write it?

For example, I brought a book from India and kept it in my home but someone stole from there, so I will write:

> Someone stole the book from my home that I brought from India.

Comment: In the last "sentence 1" what did you buy from India? What aspects of the sentence do you think are incorrect? Bare proof-reading questions are off-topic.

Comment: Stolen or stole? Stole is correct I think

Comment: I bought the book.

Comment: Avoid saying *“the **below** X”* because this can sound stilted and even
borderline unnatural to native speakers. Instead say *“the **following** 
X”* in especially formal written contexts, or merely *“**this** X”* in the
singular or *“**these** Xes”* in the plural in many common and less
exacting circumstances. Sometimes English-language learners don’t realize
that they should use the demonstrative determiners *this, that, these,
those* which native speakers customarily use for these cases.

Answer (score 1):

Original:

> I brought a book from India and kept it in my home but someone stole from there.

Suggestion:

> I brought a book from India and kept it in my home, but someone stole it.

That's a neuter pronoun and not the adjective clause you use *"someone stole the book from my home that I brought from India,"* but while that is an example of an adjective clause and is technically correct, it has a sing songy cadence that is too semantically disjointed for "localized" conversation.