# Is the word "adjectival" used in this context?

Tags: single-word-requests, grammar, vocabulary

My English Fundamentals professor keeps using the word "adjectival" as in "adjectival clause" but I can't find it being used anywhere else but his class notes. I know that the word exists but is it used in this context or in similar situations? I can't find it being used in the context of "adjectival clause". It's just adjective clause.

Comment: _adjectival_ is the adjective form of _adjective._

Comment: @user405662 Yes but I can't find it being used in the context of "adjectival clause". It's just adjective clause.

Comment: A modest dictionary search will provide an answer. Please search and return to us if you still have difficulty.

Comment: It's supposed to be the function of an adjective. But the term is misleading since it might imply that everything that modifies a noun is an adjective, which is of course untrue. The term adjective clause is most certainly to be avoided. The classification of finite subordinate clauses is based on their internal form rather than spurious analogies with the parts of speech.

Comment: @BillJ You are talking about whether you consider adjective/adjectival clauses to be a valid category. You are not addressing whether the usage is correct.

Comment: The term and the usage go hand-in-hand. And it's not a valid category, see my first comment.

Comment: The question was not: is it valid to categorize clauses in this fashion. The question is can the word "adjectival" be used in this context. And it certainly can be.

Comment: @GArthurBrown No, it can't. Clauses may be modifiers or complements etc., but they are **not** adjectival. Finite subordinate clauses are relative, comparative or content.

Comment: @jsw29 Totally irrelevant. The terms 'adjective/adjectival clause' are inappropriate. They both purport to label a clause that is adjectival in function. But this makes no sense for the reason I'm getting bored with repeating, i.e. that the classification of finite subordinate clauses is based on their internal form rather than spurious analogies with the parts of speech.

Comment: [Alisa Dial](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=oXTXDgAAQBAJ&pg=PA90&lpg=PA90&dq=%22There+are+several+different+types+of+adjectivals%22,+including+adjectives,+adjectival+prepositional+phrases,+participial+phrases,+and+relative+clauses.&source=bl&ots=01lv4OPWFb&sig=ACfU3U2H7f0pAqPfxbjj_RiLupv5KpwGDA&hl=en&sa=X&redir_esc=y#v=onepage&q=%22There%20are%20several%20different%20types%20of%20adjectivals%22%2C%20including%20adjectives%2C%20adjectival%20prepositional%20phrases%2C%20participial%20phrases%2C%20and%20relative%20clauses.&f=false) showed a traditionalist approach and terminology in an ...

Comment: article: 'there are several different types of adjectivals, including adjectives, adjectival prepositional phrases, participial phrases, and relative clauses.' But I'd say it's a very niche and vanishing usage.

Comment: 4) “Any man who hates dogs and children can’t be all bad.”  – W.C. Fields

The dependent clause “who hates dogs and children” is an adjectival clause.  **It modifies the noun “man” — it specifies what kind of man.** https://magoosh.com/gmat/gmat-grammar-adjectival-phrases-and-clauses/

Comment: But the questions is still about the usage of "adjectival" versus "adjective" by the poster's teacher and not whether this is the way you think clauses should be categorized.

Comment: @GArthurBrown The teacher **was** categorising by using the term "adjectival clause". How can we possibly tell why they used the term? And it's not the way **I** think clause should be analysed, but the way a great many other grammarians do so.

Comment: @BillJ Notwithstanding the fact that many (as demonstrated) English-teaching sources clearly use the term, that still doesn't acknowledge that use of adjectives and noun adjuncts is a grammatical and not a categorical issue. Did you reread the initial post after the update, bro?

Comment: Nonsense! Generally, only non-scholarly resources use it. Adjectives and noun adjuncts have nothing whatsoever to do with calling clauses adjectival or adjective, as I'm tired of repreatedly explaining to you. And the term 'noun adjunct' is a misnomer. Such elements are modifiers, while the term adjunct is used for modifiers in clause structure.

Answer (score 3):

adjectival clause or relative clause or adjective clause

An adjectival clause (or relative clause) is one that modifies a noun phrase. They typically are introduced by a relative pronoun, which serves as the subject of the clause. For example:
The man who lived here went to New York.
The car that came from Italy is very fast.
The apple which fell from my bag is now inedible.

[adjectival clause](https://webspace.ship.edu/cgboer/syntax.html)

there are adverbial clauses, and for parallelism's sake, there are adjectival clauses AKA relative clauses.

Relative clause
In Indo-European languages, a relative clause, also called an adjectival clause or an adjective clause, meets three requirements:

[adjectival](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependent_clause)

Sometimes, things are known by several different names.

Comment: Actually, NP complements like _the report that Congressman Frog has been re-elected_ are also adjective clauses, although relative clauses are by far the more common type. NP complements can only occur with picture nouns, usually formed from a verb (like _report_) that takes a complement.

Comment: @JohnLawler If Your Lordship would be so kind...How is the complement you cite a picture noun? All is see is the frog. [:)]

Comment: The complement is not a picture noun. It's an adjective clause (an "NP complement") modifying a picture noun. _Picture noun_ is a technical term in some theories that refers to a noun like _picture, story, report, rumor,_ etc. which are symbolic for (metaphorically, they "contain") propositions that can be expressed in clauses. It's a technical term; I didn't invent it. You can find a long discussion of it in Ross's dissertation, since NP complements, like relative clauses, are subject to the Complex Noun Phrase Constraint, one of the Ross Constraints.

Comment: @JohnLawler Ok, I see. I just don't see how that example is different from many others. But I shall take the point to the bank. Thanks.

Comment: I was just pointing out that "relative clause" and "adjective clause" are not the same, just like "object" and "direct object" are not the same. Most objects are direct objects, and most adjective clauses are relative clauses, but there are other kinds of object and adjective clause. That's all.

Comment: I wonder why BillJ isn't all over this post.

Answer (score -1):

Yes, "adjectival" is used in context. Yes, "adjective clause" is also commonly used as English can also make nouns act like adjectives. They can become modifiers, called *noun adjuncts*.

Comment: I'm sorry but that is simply untrue. Apart from the fact that the term 'adjective clause' is just nonsense (see my comment to the OP). I've no idea what you mean in this context by "English can make nouns into adjectives".

Comment: @BillJ If you need evidence that "adjective clause" is used by people in the language field, [try the site we are on](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/507422/adjective-clause). [And also here](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/555820/is-the-following-sentence-an-adjective-clause-or-an-adjective-phrase-or-a-noun-c).  [And on the English learner community forum](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/31622/adjective-clause-or-appositive-clause?rq=1). [And again, here](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/131861/can-adjectives-come-with-a-noun-directly).

Comment: @BillJ You are right that my phrasing was imprecise. I really mean that nouns are often used as modifiers in the form of adjuncts. There are not technically adjectives, but they fulfill the same role, as you can see from the example at hand.

Comment: I'm aware that some people use the term but as I said, the classification of finite subordinate clauses is based on their internal form rather than spurious analogies with the parts of speech. The so-called 'adjective clauses' are generally relative clauses functioning as **modifiers**, not adjectives.

Comment: Wake up @jsw29 There's no difference. And you are **stiil** missing the point.

Comment: Let's use a slightly different example to show Bill what the issue is. 

"My teacher says *adjectival* dog, but my text book says *adjective* dog. Which one is grammatical?" 

It doesn't matter that you don't think adjectival dogs or adjective dogs exist. The grammar rules for English are still the same.

Comment: @GArthurBrown I'm well aware of this simple issue. We're not talking about phrases here, but **clauses** (read the orig question). Clauses are not classified by functional terms or by analogies with the parts of speech. Take this on board: **The classification of finite subordinate clauses is based on their internal form rather than spurious analogies with the parts of speech**. In simple terms, neither 'adjective' not 'adjectival' are appropriate for the reasons I've given.

Comment: Right, you are still saying "adjectival dogs" don't exist.

Comment: @BillJ, given that you feel so strongly about the matter, why don't you post your views on it as an answer?